# How can I send facebook app generated requests using php?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following url for sending an app generated request to a user:

https://graph.facebook.com/apprequests/?ids=".$userid."&message=Hello&access_token=".$appToken."&method=post

This works fine if the $userid is set as current logged in user. But I am not able to send a request to my friend who is an app user and the above code throws the following error:

{"error":{"message":"(#2) Failed to create any app request","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
$app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
"client_id=" . $app_id .
"&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
"&grant_type=client_credentials";

//your app access token
$app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
$your_friend_id .
"/apprequests?message='some message'&" .
$app_access_token . "&method=post";

$result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
echo $result;
```

Hope it helps